# In react, how to remove specific item from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I have a list that I've created as I add items to it:

```js
  const addToPool = () => {
    setDiePool([
      ...diePool,
      {
        dp1 : poolCount,
        dp2 : diceType,
        dp3 : diceNumber,
        dp4 : diceAdjuster
      }
    ]);

    setPoolCount(poolCount+1);
  };
```

Now I want to remove a specific item from the list. I have all the items displaying in a table, with a delete icon next to each one.  When I click on the trash icon, I want to remove it from the list.  Its not working, but not throwing any errors either.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

my table:

```js
      <tbody>
            {diePool.map(die => (<tr key={die.dp1}><td><FaDice /></td><td>{die.dp1}</td><td>{die.dp2}</td><td>{die.dp3}</td><td>{die.dp4}</td><td><button dp1={die.dp1} onClick={handleRemoveItem}><FaTrashAlt /></button></td></tr>))}
      </tbody>
```

my remove code:

```js
  const [list, updateList] = useState(diePool);
  const handleRemoveItem = (e) => {
     const dp1 = e.target.getAttribute("dp1")
     updateList(list.filter(diePool => diePool.dp1 !== dp1));
   };
```

Comment: handleRemoveItem should be invoked within a useEffect hook no?

Comment: @BrandonBailey why would he need useEffect?  He is invoking the function on the click of a button.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(dp1)` in your handleRemoveItem function do you get the correct value?

Comment: Are you using a different `useState` hook for the add and the remove? one calls `setDiePool` and one calls `updateList`?

Comment: The filter looks correct as far as I can tell, but if you're modifying different states then that would definitely cause it to not display as expected

Comment: Probably `e.target` is referencing to `FaTrashAlt` element instead of `button` element. Try using `e.currentTarget` instead

Comment: @SteveK I dont know, hence the question. I thought the button triggers a state change, as hooks are being used, wouldn't useEffect need to be used?

Comment: @BrandonBailey you can read about `useEffect` on reacts docs.  `useEffect` is used to invoke something when a value in the dependency array of the effect is changed.  `useEffect` is a hook itself not required to use hooks.  There is no reason to `useEffect` here because he is invoking the state change on a button click so `useEffect` would be irrelevant here.

Comment: @SteveK ah ok that makes sense now. thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass die to handleRemoveItem as params, this should work:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function App() {
  const [diePool, setDiePool] = React.useState([
    {
      dp1: "poolCount",
      dp2: "diceType",
      dp3: "diceNumber",
      dp4: "diceAdjuster"
    },
    {
      dp1: "poolCount1",
      dp2: "diceType1",
      dp3: "diceNumber1",
      dp4: "diceAdjuster1"
    }
  ]);

  const handleRemoveItem = die => {
    setDiePool(diePool.filter(diePool => diePool.dp1 !== die.dp1));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {diePool.map(die => (
        <tr key={die.dp1}>
          <td>
            <span>test</span>
          </td>
          <td>{die.dp1}</td>
          <td>{die.dp2}</td>
          <td>{die.dp3}</td>
          <td>{die.dp4}</td>
          <td>
            <button dp1={die.dp1} onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(die)}>
              <span>FaTrashAlt</span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be passing the value in the `handleRemoveItem` function.

```
<button dp1={die.dp1} onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(dp1)}><FaTrashAlt /></button>

const handleRemoveItem = (item) => {
     updateList(list.filter(diePool => diePool.dp1 !== item));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `useState` it looks to be unnecessary and will not update the state that you're mapping over for your table.

```js
// Remove this
// const [list, updateList] = useState(diePool); 

const handleRemoveItem = (e) => {
  const dp1 = e.target.getAttribute("dp1") 
  // use the setter from the original state hook
  setDiePool(diePool.filter(die => die.dp1 !== dp1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `const dp1 = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("dp1")` instead of `const dp1 = e.target.getAttribute("dp1")` in handleRemoveItem

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget